# How to get the selected build configuration (on a property page) programmatically in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, build, eclipse-cdt

The task is to get the selected build configuration on the project's property page.

I have tried to achieve this by writing the following code:

```
private static IConfiguration getSelectedBuildConf(IProject proj) {
    IManagedBuildInfo info = ManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(proj);
    if (info == null) {
        return null;            
    } else {
        IConfiguration cfg = info.getSelectedConfiguration();
        return cfg;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that getSelectedConfiguration() always returns null.

getSelectedConfiguration() returns always Debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use getDefaultConfiguration() instead of getSelectedConfiguration()...

As [explained on cdt-dev list here](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg09758.html).

Comment: I use getDefaultConfiguration() now but the problem is that after selecting Release configuration from the Settings property page the Debug configuration is still the active configuration. As far as I know the getDefaultConfiguration() returns the active configuration.